# Couldn't get location coordinates from JSON dataset

Tags: ios, json, mapkit

I'm trying to develop an app for parking using ray wenderlich iOS mapkit tutorial as a model. While parsing the JSON dataset, the dataset in the tutorial has latitudes and longitudes separately. But in my dataset, they are together and therefore could not get them properly. So how to get the location coordinates??

This is the code given:

```
let latitude = (json[18].string! as NSString).doubleValue
let longitude = (json[19].string! as NSString).doubleValue
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
```

Since, I don't have the lat and long separately, this won't work.
My JSON dataset has it like this:

```
"format" : { }
  }, {
    "id" : 203383710,
    "name" : "Latitude, Longitude",
    "dataTypeName" : "text",
    "fieldName" : "latitude_longitude",
    "position" : 4,
    "renderTypeName" : "text",
    "tableColumnId" : 28269463,
    "width" : 328,
    "cachedContents" : {
      "non_null" : 83,
      "largest" : "21.316161, -157.862061",
      "null" : 123,
      "top" : [ {
        "item" : "21.306760, -157.861027",
        "count" : 20
      } ],
      "smallest" : "21.275168, -157.824498"
    },


[ [ 1, "D8CA6E89-DA04-424A-8DE3-9620EFE0A2EF", 1, 1431455105, "906163",
1431455105, "906163", "{\n}", "000 Aloha Tower Drive", null, null, null,
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
null, null, null, [ "
{\"address\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"zip\":\"\"}", null, null,
null, true ] ]
```

So, how to get this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string that equals "abc, def" and you want to separate it into the part before the comma and the part after the comma, you can use `string.componentsSeparatedByString(", ")`.

This will return an array.  The first element of the array (in the example above) will be "abc" and the second element will be "def".  Note that the argument in the call is ", " -- that is, not just a comma, but a comma followed by a space, since the latitude and longitude in your JSON appear to separated with a comma followed by a space.

Comment: Thx. But when I tried to convert them to double to use them in CLLocationCoordinate2D, I couldn't. What would be the mistake?? 'let str = (json[10].string! as NSString)
        let numbers = str.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: ", "))
        let latitude = (numbers.first)
        let longitude = (numbers.last)
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
'

Comment: Instead of your code for setting latitude and longitude, do this: `let latitude = Double(numbers.first)` and `let longitude = Double(numbers.last)`.  Then check to make sure neither latitude nor longitude are nil, and if they are not, do this:  `let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)`.

Comment: Thx. Now I got it. Had a problem with my dataset then. It was null and so couldn't get values. Now, its working alright. Thx again.